# Set html lang attribute on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a multilingual rails application. 
On the base.html.erb I am setting the lang attribute like that :

```
<html lang="<%= I18n.locale %>" ng-app="myApp">
```

Is that a good way to do it or there is a better one ?

Comment: Looks right to me http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations

Comment: Hi,

I am not sure because when I dynamically change the language, it does not reload the page and then does not change the html language. Except if you have a different behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It might work okay; although you might prefer setting the current locale within your controllers for better flexibility

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :current_locale
  ...

  private

  def current_locale
    @current_locale ||= begin
      # complex logic, switching locale based on
      # user defined locale, subdomain, params, etc...
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your view :

```
<html lang="<%= current_locale %>" ng-app="myApp">
...
```

Comment: The approach used in the question does indeed set the locale in ApplicationController. I18n's getter 'locale' is simply being called to get the value in the view. The questioner's approach is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Using `I18n.locale`, which *gets* the locale for the current request is right-on if you want to use its value in a template. If you want to *set* the locale based on some logic for each request, consider calling a `set_locale` method in an `around_action` in ApplicationController. This example looks for a persisted user-selected locale, then looks for a cookie value, then defaults to the app config value. This also allows you to use and set a locale (via the cookie) for *public* pages in your app.

```
around_action :set_locale

def set_locale(&action)
  # nil until set either as user attribute or via the signin page
  locale = cookies[:locale]
  if current_user
    # Check a logged-in user's locale attribute. Changing the attribute is
    # done via AJAX then reload, so this works when changing the attribute
    locale = current_user.try(:locale)
    cookies[:locale] = locale
  elsif params[:locale]
    # Set the locale cookie via a public page
    locale = params[:locale].to_sym
    cookies[:locale] = locale
  end
  I18n.with_locale(locale || I18n.default_locale, &action)
end
```

Then in any controller or view/layout, just as you have it:

```
<%= I18n.locale %>
```